# Java Server and chunked data

Tags: java, http

I am writing a http server in java using ServerSocket and Socket respectively.

In specification it says that the request can be of "chunked" type. So how could I enable this option in any browser to test the parsing of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make up the request on your own:

```
POST /search HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Length: 25

000a
q=23456789
000a
0123456789
0005
01234
0
```

This request is split into three parts, and your server should receive `q=23456789012345678901234` as the POST data.

Note: you need another CRLF at the end of the request, which this markup language cannot display.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK most desktop browsers don't send chunked requests because some web servers don't handle them correctly (or at all) and it's easier to calculate the length than to detect/guess/remember which servers support it.

The [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) command-line tool can send chunked requests:

```
curl -v -d "name=value" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" http://foo.com/bar
```